# I am trying to build a land registry of land titles on the blockchain,

Tags: contract-development, transactions, blockchain, contract-design, dapps

Good Day. I am trying to build a land registry of land titles on the blockchain, with the intention of being able to sell such title to someone else. Therefore, the title eventually has to be transferred to the buyer. How will the title be represented in the blockchain? Should I tokenize it? If so, how? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume each title is unique and non-divisible. If that is the case then you should look into ERC-721 tokens. They are so-called NFT tokens (Non-Fungible Tokens) which are meant for unique and indivisible assets.

So each title could be represented by one unique NFT. It supports all the functionality you listed. You can read more for example here: http://erc721.org/

Comment: What about divisible titles?

Comment: Quick google gave me: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/864 and https://hackernoon.com/the-future-of-virtual-assets-introducing-the-fractional-nft-84c218da73c9